# .net cms for QnA that can be integrated with existing web form application

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

i have a working web form asp.net website build in asp.net 3.5.

i want a QnA section or pages or module in my website.

i have searched for cms in .net which can fulfill this requirement and **can be integrated with my existing website (not in MVC)** but have not found a suitable one.

can u guide me some cms for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have usercontrols in your application, I would suggest that you use dot net nuke. You can easly convert your usercontrols in DNN modules.